# How to get items from a list but only after a condition is met?

Tags: python, list

If I have a list

```
x=[0.0,0.0,2.0,3.0,0.0,2.0]
```

and I basically want to count the amount of items in the list but only start after the leading zeroes, how would I do that? Keep in mind that I want to count the zero in the middle of the list but not the ones at the beginning.

I’ve tried this:

```
n=0
for i in x:
    while i==0.0:
       break
    if i!=0.0:
       n=n+1
```

But it didn’t get 4, which is the output I want as I want to include 2.0,3.0,0.0,2.0 only.

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: To get started, what if you counted the number of leading 0 items and used that with the count of all items "somehow" :-)

Comment: I thought the expected output here is `4`, but apparently other people have different opinions (see answers below which use `Counter`). It is why you must provide a sincere attempt, or at least an expected output, to resolve ambiguity.

Comment: I see what you did.  The while does nothing and your loop ends up counting the non-zeroes. See the answers for ways of doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply wrap your counter code in a conditional, with something like this:

```
x=[0.0,0.0,2.0,3.0,0.0,2.0]
start_counting = False
item_count = 0

for i in x:
    if i != 0.0:
        start_counting = True
    if start_counting:
        item_count += 1
```

`item_count` will now have the amount of items in the list without the starting 0.0s

Answer (score 5):

You can use `itertools.dropwhile`

```
from itertools import dropwhile
from collections import Counter

data = [0.0,0.0,2.0,3.0,0.0,2.0]
print(sum(1 for _ in dropwhile(lambda x: x == 0, data))) # 4

print(Counter(dropwhile(lambda x: x == 0, data))) # Counter({2.0: 2, 3.0: 1, 0.0: 1})
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to make this an easy one-liner is to turn the list into a string, with the zeroes transformed into whitespace; this allows you to use `str.lstrip()`:

```
>>> x=[0.0,0.0,2.0,3.0,0.0,2.0]
>>> len(''.join("*" if i else " " for i in x).lstrip())
4
```

Answer (score 1):

```
x=[0.0,0.0,2.0,3.0,0.0,2.0]
while x[0] == 0:
    x = x[1:]
print(len(x))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your added code is conceptually close:

```py
n=0
for i in x:
    ## -----------------
    ## the problem here is you are not incrementing "i"
    ## -----------------
    while i==0.0:
       break
    ## -----------------
    if i!=0.0:
       n=n+1
```

Let's take your idea an use it to count just the number of leading 0.0 items:

```py
count_leading_zeros = 0
for item in x:
    if item == 0.0:
        count_leading_zeros += 1
        continue
    break
```

That will give us `2` and a simple `len(x)` is `6` and `6 - 2 == 4`

Cleaning up the for loop above to do the same as we have done as:

```py
for item in x:
    if item != 0.0:
        break
    count_leading_zeros += 1
```

We can create a complete answer as:

```py
x=[0.0,0.0,2.0,3.0,0.0,2.0]
count_all = len(x)
count_leading_zeros = 0
for item in x:
    if item != 0.0:
        break
    count_leading_zeros += 1
print(count_all - count_leading_zeros)
```

I feel this is the most straightforward approach, but you have lots of great ones to select from if you feel this is not "pythonic".

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the 'set()' function to remove duplicate values from your list, then you can be sure that the second element in this set is the first value after the zeroes, this value can be extracted by converting the set to a tuple or a list and using the indices, when you know what the first value is after the zeros, you can find it's position using the 'index()' function and that position is where you need to start counting, so if you subtract this position from the list length you get the list items after the first non-zero value.

```
x = [0.0, 0.0, 2.0, 3.0, 0.0, 2.0]
print(len(x) - x.index(tuple(set(x))[1])
```